# Solr Spellcheck Query term modification

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I am using Solr for spell checking. Enabled both DirectSolrSpellChecker & WordBreakSolrSpellChecker. I have the following issue:

A. When I am querying for "worry". Solr is converting this term to "worri" and returning results for the same. If word is ending with "y" [ "injury","worry" etc..], the ending "y" is replaced with "i".

Example Query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/MY_CORE/spell?df=text&spellcheck.q=worry&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=true
```

Solr Result:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">5</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions">
<lst name="worri">
<int name="numFound">9</int>
<int name="startOffset">0</int>
<int name="endOffset">5</int>
<int name="origFreq">5</int>
<arr name="suggestion">
<lst>
<str name="word">wo r ri</str>
<int name="freq">90</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">worst</str>
<int name="freq">12</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">wo r r i</str>
<int name="freq">5246</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">work</str>
<int name="freq">2920</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">w o r ri</str>
<int name="freq">530</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">worn</str>
<int name="freq">81</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">w o r r i</str>
<int name="freq">5246</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">wors</str>
<int name="freq">79</int>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="word">worm</str>
<int name="freq">10</int>
</lst>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>
<bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
</lst>
</response>
```

B. Also above output have words like "w o r r i", and I couldn't find any of those words in the solr field. I also don't know why solr is returning such words where letters are separated by spaces.

Below is schema file:

```
<field name=MY FIELD type="text_en" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Below is the config file:

```
<!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="field"> MY FIELD </str>
            <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
            <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
            <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
            <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
            <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
            <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
            <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
            <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
            <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
            <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
            <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
            <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
            <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
            <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
            <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
            <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
             <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
             -->
        </lst>

        <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->

         <lst name="spellchecker">
         <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
         <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
         <str name="field">MY FIELD</str>
         <str name="combineWords">false</str>
         <str name="breakWords">true</str>
         <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
         </lst>

    </searchComponent>


    <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
            <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">false</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>spellcheck</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

**I would really appreciate if someone can help me regarding this.**

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "strange" suggestions that you have like "wo r r i". You have them, because you're using [WordBreakSolrSpellChecker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking) and it breaks tokens trying to provide you some spellcheck capabilities, so if you will remove you shouldn't get these kind of suggestions. Here is the quote from the official documentation:

> WordBreakSolrSpellChecker offers suggestions by combining adjacent
>   query terms and/or breaking terms into multiple words. It is a
>   SpellCheckComponent enhancement, leveraging Lucene's
>   WordBreakSpellChecker. It can detect spelling errors resulting from
>   misplaced whitespace without the use of shingle-based dictionaries and
>   provides collation support for word-break errors, including cases
>   where the user has a mix of single-word spelling errors and word-break
>   errors in the same query. It also provides shard support.

So, basically, in your example - you're getting normal suggestions from Solr index like: `worst, work, worm, worn, wors`. all other are just the result of WordBreakSolrSpellChecker and you will never find them in your index.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Do you have any idea about the first issue? If a word is ending with "y", solr is replacing it with "i" and providing spell checking for the same.

Comment: probably there some stemming in your schema. could you share it?